# Why does opening the Chrome Console solve long wait issue?

Tags: django, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-console

My colleagues & I are building an Angular 4 app with a Django back-end.  Periodically we have to wait a long time for a request to go out from the UI to the web-server.  Yet if one opens up the Chrome Console then this seems to effect the request to immediately go out and provide the desired response.

We're trying to get a handle on what's going on.  Any ideas?

Robert